# Remove thousand separator from all price display- Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I want to display the price without **','**.
 My current format is : **ر.س.‏ 1٬105.00**
But I need : **ر.س.‏ 1105.0**0

I tried to remove from locale. But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the above question. Solution is,

I **changed the currency format** in below-mentioned file.

```
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/<languagecode>.xml
```