# Custom Pricing Question

Tags: magento2, backend, admin-panel, special-price, advanced-pricing

I use Magento 2.4.3. and I want to delete the thousands separator in magento prices.

For example for in place of this price "2,100.00 €" I want to have "2100.00 €"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270007/remove-thousand-separator-from-all-price-display-magento-2/270481

Comment: i didnt understand the path btw can you explain where the path?